# CD drive keeps popping out on Dell D630 when using Fedora but fine with Windows XP

Tags: laptop, fedora, dell-latitude

I have a Dell D630 laptop that I did a clean install of Fedora on last weekend. Every time I open the CD drive and close it, it pops open again after a couple seconds. This happens whether or not it has a CD in it.

This has only happened under Fedora; under the late Crunchbang and Windows XP this never happened. Anybody know anything I could try?

Comment: Omg, a D630 that still runs...amazing laptops.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could be a couple of different things.

Could be hardware failure/malfunction based on what I'm reading (I'm reading it as though it's chronological because you haven't supplied more data).

http://www.howtogeek.com/forum/topic/cd-drive-keeps-opening?PageSpeed=noscript

Could also be a software malfunction/conflict which results in this strange behaviour as well. In one case, software for a USB dongle was actually interpreting the device as a mass storage device (driver install software) which meant that from time to time ejection of the optical drive could be a side-effect.

http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1489234

Comment: I don't think it's hardware as I've only experienced the bug under Fedora, as I mentioned in the OP. I also haven't installed any software except Firefox.

Comment: Ok I just booted up Tails on a flash drive and it's still happening, so it's probably either hardware or malware.